# Creating a PDF File in PDFBOX (from existing pdf file)

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox

I have a 300 page PDF file. I want to create a new PDF file from my chosen pages the existing pdf file.

I have created a blank PDF File (using PDFBox ) like this:

```
 // Create a new empty document
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

// Create a new blank page and add it to the document
PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
document.addPage( blankPage );

// Save the newly created document
document.save("BlankPage.pdf");
```

and this is how I am reading a page from pdf File.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("Hello World.pdf");
PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(67);
```

My question is, how do I get the contents of 'firstpage' into "blankPage.pdf". 
If I can choose the x,y coordinates of the firstpage(where it is to be overlayed), it would be even better.

**P.S. 
The page sizes of my Hello World file are not A4.Each page is more like a thumbnail with text and shapes.So, overlaying is possible on A4. Also, I do not want to convert the files to image and then onverlay, I want the whole pdf file to be pasted as is(without converting to image first)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that iText can do the same thing.Here is the code for that :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Hello World.pdf");

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("RESULT.PDF"));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfImportedPage page;








            for (int i = 3; i <=6; i++) {
                page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                canvas.addTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1, 0, i*30-250);

            }
            document.close();
```